# Difference of inverese matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$, $B$ be symmetric positive definite matrices. We know

$$
A^{-1}-B^{-1}=-C
$$

for positive semidefinite matrix $C$.

I want to show that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite. Here's my take:

\begin{aligned}
A^{-1}+-B^{-1}&=-C\\
(A^{-1}+-B^{-1})^{-1}&=-C^{-1}\\
-A(A-B)^{-1}B&=-C^{-1}\\
(A-B)^{-1}&=(BCA)^{-1}\\
A-B&=BCA
\end{aligned}
where the third line uses the identity $\left(\mathbf{A}^{-1}+\mathbf{B}^{-1}\right)^{-1}=\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^{-1} \mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^{-1} \mathbf{A}$.

Now $A$,$B$ are positive definite and $C$ positive semidefinite. Do we know of a result that shows $BCA$ and so $A-B$ is positive semidefinite?

I would appreciate your confirmation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to include your thoughts and why you have asked this.

Comment: $A-B=A^{1/2}\big(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}\big)^{1/2}A^{1/2}(B^{-1}-A^{-1})A^{1/2}\big(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}\big)^{1/2}A^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks, though not sure how that helps, please elaborate.

Comment: In the case of positive semidefinite $C$, you must also ensure it is invertible; however, you implicitly assumed this which is not always the case.

Comment: Does this matter, though? If I use the identity $A^{-1}+-B^{-1}=((A^{-1}+-B^{-1})^{-1})^{-1}$ from the second line onward I arrive at the same result without taking the possibly non-existent inverse of $C$.